# Passing data from a class that 'extends activity' to a class that 'extends fragment'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, fragment

What i'm trying to do is to send information obtained in a class that 'extends activity' to a class that 'extends fragment' where this 'extends fragment' is part of a 'PagerAdapter'

My initial thought was to pass the information through an intent to the class that 'extends fragment activity' and then pass the information to the appropriate fragment using 'getActivity().getIntent.getExtras()' but this doesn't seem to work, as the information has to be displayed in a textView.

My classes are displayed below..

**ObtainUserInformation.java**

```
public class ObtainUserInformation extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.obtain_user_information);
}

public void submitInformation(View view){
    EditText maintenanceTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.obUserInfo_maintenence);
    EditText grantTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.obUserInfo_grant);
    EditText bursaryTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.obUserInfo_bursary);
    EditText barclaysTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.obUserInfo_barclays);
    EditText natwestTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.obUserInfo_natwest);
    EditText hsbcTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.obUserInfo_hsbc);
    EditText walletTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.obUserInfo_wallet);

    String maintenance = maintenanceTxt.getText().toString();
    String grant = grantTxt.getText().toString();
    String bursary = bursaryTxt.getText().toString();
    String barclays = barclaysTxt.getText().toString();
    String natwest = natwestTxt.getText().toString();
    String hsbc = hsbcTxt.getText().toString();
    String wallet = walletTxt.getText().toString();

    if(maintenance.isEmpty()|| grant.isEmpty() || bursary.isEmpty() || barclays.isEmpty() || natwest.isEmpty()
            || hsbc.isEmpty() || wallet.isEmpty()){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Empty textbox!"); 
        builder.setMessage("Please enter 0.00 for any empty textboxes"); builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    }
    else{
        float convMaintenance = Float.valueOf(maintenance);
        float convGrant = Float.valueOf(grant);
        float convBursary = Float.valueOf(bursary);
        float convBarclays = Float.valueOf(barclays);
        float convNatwest = Float.valueOf(natwest);
        float convHsbc = Float.valueOf(hsbc);
        float convWallet = Float.valueOf(wallet);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ObtainUserInformation.this, MainMenu.class);
        intent.getFloatExtra("maintenance", convMaintenance);
        intent.getFloatExtra("grant", convGrant);
        intent.getFloatExtra("bursary", convBursary);
        intent.getFloatExtra("barclays", convBarclays);
        intent.getFloatExtra("natwest", convNatwest);
        intent.getFloatExtra("hsbc", convHsbc);
        intent.getFloatExtra("wallet", convWallet);
        Toast.makeText(ObtainUserInformation.this, "Financial information successfully saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

}

What this class is doing is to grab the users input on an EditText, put them into variables, and send these variables through an intent.

**MainMenu.java**

```
public class MainMenu extends FragmentActivity{

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); //Initiate DB class methods
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

//OnCreate
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);   
}

**UNNCESSARY CODE OMMITED**

public void getUserInformation() {
    float maintenance = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("maintenance");
    float grant = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("grant");
    float bursary = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("bursary");
    float barclays = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("barclays");
    float natwest = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("natwest");
    float hsbc = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("hsbc");
    float wallet = getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("wallet");
    EditText maintenanceTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fragment3_maintenance);
    EditText grantTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fragment3_grant);
    EditText bursaryTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fragment3_bursary);
    EditText barclaysTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fragment3_barclays);
    EditText natwestTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fragment3_natwest);
    EditText hsbcTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fragment3_hsbc);
    EditText walletTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fragment3_wallet);
    maintenanceTxt.setTextSize(maintenance);
    grantTxt.setTextSize(grant);
    bursaryTxt.setTextSize(bursary);
    barclaysTxt.setTextSize(barclays);
    natwestTxt.setTextSize(natwest);
    hsbcTxt.setTextSize(hsbc);
    walletTxt.setTextSize(wallet);
}

MORE UNNECESSARY CODE OMITTED
```

What this class contains is a method 'getUserInformation' that grabs the intent, finds the EditText id and sets the intent variable to this text field.

**Fragment3**

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3, container, false);

    //Set date to TextView
    long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
    String dateString = sdf.format(date);
    TextView t = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.textView_date3);
    t.setText(dateString);
    return root;
}
```

This class is where I want the variables to be displayed in EditText boxes but struggling to find a suitable method to complete this task.

It becomes more difficult when working with fragments instead of ordinary activity classes...

Just a break down of what I want to happen is:
1.) User enters information to a 1 time activity
2.) This information is displayed in a fragment that's part of a pagerAdapter

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Bundle like this if you want to pass data while creating the Fragment.

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("yourStringName", yourSting);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

If you want to contact the enclosing activity from fragment. You can get the `Activity` instance using `getActivity` method and call the function you wanted to call. In your case even you can access the Intent associated with the `FragmentActivity` and access the extra values from it.

[public void putFloat (String key, float value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putFloat%28java.lang.String,%20float%29)

Comment: In my case i'm trying to pass a float over, would this still work the same way instead of using `args.putInt("yourStringName", yourString);`?

Comment: Also do I use the `getActivity` under the `onCreateView` in my `Fragment3` class, or do I have to create a seperate method in my `Fragment3` that utilises the `getActivity` functionality?

Comment: override onActivityCreated method.

Comment: Would it be possible if you could provide some code to how I could implement this according to my structure?